# If-Then-Else DSL - define implicits to distinguish two return types

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I am trying to build a small DSL that allows some if-then-else branches with two types of composition, one generic (`If`) and one with added capabilities (`IfGE`). I was under the impression that with mixing in a low priority implicit trait I can make Scala select the more precise return type for the `Else` operation, but it fails. Here is the construction:

**Edit**: Here is a minimal case. Further below is a more thorough walk-through of the context. For answering the question, probably focusing on this minimal case is sufficient, while to understand what I'm doing the longer example might be better.

---

```
trait GE
trait If[A] {
  def Else[B >: A, Out](cond: => B)(implicit result: Result[B, Out]): Out
}
trait IfGE extends If[GE] with GE

case class SinOsc()     extends GE
case class WhiteNoise() extends GE

trait LowPri {
  implicit def AnyRes[A]: Result[A, If[A]] = ???  // !
}
object Result extends LowPri {
  implicit def GERes: Result[GE, IfGE] = ???
}
sealed trait Result[A, Out]

def IfExample: If[SinOsc]

val res1: GE = IfExample.Else(WhiteNoise())
val res2: GE = IfExample.Else[GE, IfGE](WhiteNoise())
```

Here, type inference and implicit resolution fails for `res1`, while explicitly putting the types in `res2` makes it work. I need to get `res1` working, i.e. without specifying the type parameters.

---

Longer example:

(1) A graph element with some implicits to use numbers as graph elements and apply binary operators:

```
object GE {
  implicit def intIsGE   (x: Int   ): GE = ???
  implicit def doubleIsGE(x: Double): GE = ???

  implicit class GEOps(private val ge: GE) extends AnyVal {
    def <= (that: GE): GE = ???
    def >  (that: GE): GE = ???
    def &  (that: GE): GE = ???
    def poll(): Unit = ???
  }
}
trait GE
```

(2) A branching structure:

```
object If {
  def apply(cond: => GE): IfBuilder = ???
}

trait IfBuilder {
  def Then [A](branch: => A): If[A]
}

trait If[A] {
  def Else: ElseBuilder[A]
  def ElseIf(cond: => GE): ElseIfBuilder[A]
}

trait IfGE extends If[GE] with GE

object ElseBuilder {
  trait LowPri {
    implicit def AnyRes[A]: Result[A, If[A]] = ???
  }
  object Result extends LowPri {
    implicit def GERes: Result[GE, IfGE] = ???
  }
  sealed trait Result[A, Out]
}
trait ElseBuilder[A] {
  def apply[B >: A, Out](b: => B)(implicit res: ElseBuilder.Result[B, Out]): Out
}

trait ElseIfBuilder[A] {
  def Then [B >: A](branch: => B): If[B]
}
```

(3) Some example graph elements:

```
case class Out(signal: GE)
case class SinOsc(freq: GE) extends GE
case class Dust(freq: GE) extends GE
case class WhiteNoise() extends GE
```

(4) A test suite:

```
trait Tests {
  def freq: GE

  // ---- Unit/Any result ----

  val res0 = If (freq > 600) Then {
    Out(SinOsc(freq))
  }

  val res1 = If (freq > 400 & freq <= 600) Then {
    Out(SinOsc(freq))
  } Else {
    freq.poll()
  }

  // ---- GE result ----

  val res2: GE = If (freq > 100) Then {
    SinOsc(freq)
  } Else {
    WhiteNoise()
  }

  val res3: GE = If (freq > 1000) Then {
    SinOsc(freq)
  } ElseIf (freq > 100) Then {
    Dust(freq)
  } Else {
    WhiteNoise()
  }

  Out(res3)
}
```

But the last two tests (`res2` and `res3`) do not work. The return type is not `IfGE` apparently but only `If[GE]`. **How can I fix this, so that the last two examples find `GERes` instead of `AnyRes`?**

Comment: side comment - having written a DSL on a previous work project, I strongly recommend Debasish Ghosh's [DSLs in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/dsls-in-action). He covers DSLs in multiple languages, and devotes a few chapters to Scala (using implicits + parser combinator library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your shorter example:

Definition `implicit def GERes: Result[GE, IfGE]` corresponds to type `GE` exactly, but `WhiteNoise()` has type `WhiteNoise <: GE`, and that doesn't fit the implicit.

---

You can either change the definition of the implicit to work for child types of `GE`:

```
object Result extends LowPri {
  implicit def GERes[T <: GE]: Result[T, IfGE] = ???
}
```

---

Or define `Result` to be contravariant in its first type parameter. That will make the implicits work for subtypes as well:

```
sealed trait Result[-A, Out]
object Result extends LowPri {
  implicit def GERes: Result[GE, IfGE] = ???
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I thought it must be a variance annotation, but probably I played around with them at a different state of the code. Works now for both the short and the large case.